# SQLSyntaxErrorException: Columns of type 'DOUBLE' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR'

Tags: java

I write code in java such as

```
Double Alish = Double.valueOf(productAlishText.getText().toString());
Double Satish = Double.valueOf(productSatishText.getText().toString());
Query = "INSERT INTO MALLAR (CUSTOMERID,PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTALISH,PRODUCTSATISH) "
                    + "VALUES ('" + getEkspeditorIndex() + "','" + productAdiText.getText() + "','" + Alish+ "','" + Satish+ "')";
stat.execute(Query);
```

but this code give this error.

> SQLSyntaxErrorException: Columns of type 'DOUBLE' cannot hold values
>   of type 'CHAR'

Comment: Show your ddl and use prepared statements.

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` instead of concatenating strings together into an SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

You're quoting your `Double` values as well. Remove the quotes.

```
Query = "INSERT INTO MALLAR (CUSTOMERID,PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTALISH,PRODUCTSATISH) "
        + "VALUES ('" + getEkspeditorIndex() + "','" + productAdiText.getText()
        + "'," + Alish+ "," + Satish+ ")";
```

Notice, there are no quotes `''` around `Alish` and `Satish` above.

But, I'll suggest you to use a `PreparedStatement` instead. Not only do you get rid of such concatenation problems, you prevent SQL injection attacks as well.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MALLAR " 
    + "(CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTALISH, PRODUCTSATISH) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

pstmt.setString(1, getEkspeditorIndex());
pstmt.setString(2, productAdiText.getText());
pstmt.setDouble(3, Alish);
pstmt.setDouble(4, Satish);

pstmt.executeUpdate();
```